# Iterating JSON list results in a "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, syntax

I have an AJAX call, which calls a controller. This controller returns the following JSON:

```
{"officeProducts":"[{\"Id\":96,\"MyProperty\":null,\"Enabled\":true,\"Envelope\":{\"Id\":1,\"Quality\":\"God\",\"PaperSize\":\"A4\",\"Type\":\"Window\"}},{\"Id\":169,\"MyProperty\":null,\"Enabled\":true,\"Envelope\":{\"Id\":1,\"Quality\":\"God\",\"PaperSize\":\"A4\",\"Type\":\"Window\"}},{\"Id\":174,\"MyProperty\":null,\"Enabled\":true,\"Envelope\":{\"Id\":1,\"Quality\":\"God\",\"PaperSize\":\"A4\",\"Type\":\"Window\"}},{\"Id\":175,\"MyProperty\":null,\"Enabled\":true,\"Envelope\":{\"Id\":1,\"Quality\":\"God\",\"PaperSize\":\"A4\",\"Type\":\"Window\"}}]"}
```

And now I want to iterate the list. So I basically want to iterate the `officeProducts`.

I have the following code, where I obviously do something wrong, as I get a:

Error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"Id":96,"MyProperty":null,"Enabled":true,"Envelope":{"Id":1,"Quality":"God","PaperSize":"A4","Type":"Window"}},{"Id":169,"MyProperty":null,"Enabled":true,"Envelope":{"Id":1,"Quality":"God","PaperSize":"A4","Type":"Window"}},{"Id":174,"MyProperty":null,"Enabled":true,"Envelope":{"Id":1,"Quality":"God","PaperSize":"A4","Type":"Window"}},{"Id":175,"MyProperty":null,"Enabled":true,"Envelope":{"Id":1,"Quality":"God","PaperSize":"A4","Type":"Window"}}]
```

My AJAX call:

```
self.updateOfficeProducts = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/SingleLetter/GetOfficeProducts',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'country': self.countryId
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.officeProducts);

            $(data.officeProducts).each(function (index, ele) {
               alert(ele.Id);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

So I would expect to iterate 4 different objects, where I can say things like `ele.Id` or `ele.Enabled`. Instead I get my syntax error.

What am I doing wrong? :-) Obviously some syntax thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)-

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $(data.officeProducts).each(function (index, ele) {
       alert(ele.Id);
    });
    ...
```

**Edit**

Another thing — I'm not sure of .NET, but the response you're getting back is not of the form expected by ajax. The string is not properly json-encoded.

You have to remove  `"` before and after the `[` and  `]`, so the string would be-

```
var a = '{"officeProducts": [{\"Id\":96,\"MyProperty\":null,\"Enabled\":true,\"Envelope\":{\"Id\":1,\"Quality\":\"God\",\"PaperSize\":\"A4\",\"Type\":\"Window\"}}] }';
//                         ^here                                                                                                                           and here^
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9v6vV/2/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi. If I use "JSON.parse" or "$.parse" like that I get:

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

Comment: You might not be sending the data from PHP in correct form. If you are making a database query there and returning the response just do this- store every thing in the `stdClass/Array` then just return the `json_encode($result)` from PHP and here in js, `JSON.parse(data)` will fetch the result properly

Comment: Hmm I already do that. I use C#/.NET, and my code is:  return Json(new {
                officeProducts = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(models)   
            }); (which is the same as json_encode)